# Как объединить три таблицы с помощью sql и вывести маркер пролайканности?

Tags: mysql, sql, json

Есть три таблицы. Посты — записи. Пользователи — авторы постов. Лайки — лайки пользователей. Нужно объединить три таблицы таким образом, чтобы на экране отображался список постов с указанием логина автора и с указанием маркера пролайканности.

```
- post -
id_post, id_user, datetime, title, description

- user - 
id_user, login, email, password, token

- likes -
id_likes, datetime, id_user, id_post
```

У пользователя есть уникальный токен и по нему скрипт должен выдать маркер пролайканности постов в формате json для данного пользователя.

Пример:

```
[{"id_post":1,"datetime":"JUL 04 2021","title":"Test header 1","login":"admin","id_user":"1","is_liked":"0"},
{"id_post":2,"datetime":"JUL 05 2021","title":"Test header 2","login":"seo","id_user":"2","is_liked":"1"}]
```

Предполагаю, что это можно решить или с помощью подзапросов или скрипта. Хотелось бы найти оптимальный вариант решения данного вопроса.

Comment: для объединения таблиц используются операторы JOIN. вашем случае для автора поста будет inner join, а для лайков текущего пользователя - left join

Comment: про объединение знаю, но вариант с лайками не подходит под объединение, насколько я понимаю

Comment: чем же не подходит?

Comment: тем, что по сути это не объединение, а условие, что если для данного поста  найдена в таблице лайков запись за авторством указанного пользователя, то нужно создать в поле "is_liked" 1, иначе 0

Comment: Если уж вам прямо 1 и 0 надо то, `(case when id_likes is null then 0 else 1 end) as is_liked`. А если без этого, то при левом джойне будете получать null, если лайка не было, и его id, если он был. Этих сведений вполне достаточно, кажется?

Comment: Всё равно не понимаю, как это поможет.
По сути есть таблица с постами. И для каждого поста нужно проверить, ставил ли на нём лайк пользователь с ИД = 1.
Получаем все посты — это понятно. А для каждого поста получить отдельную колонку, в которую встанет результат подзапроса — не понятно.